# ELKI clustering FDBSCAN algorithm

Tags: cluster-analysis, dbscan, elki

Please could you show me example of input file for FDBSCAN in [ELKI](https://elki-project.github.io/). I got error like this:

```
Task failed
de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.data.type.NoSupportedDataTypeException: No data type found satisfying: UncertainObject,field
Available types: DBID DoubleVector,dim=2
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.database.AbstractDatabase.getRelation(AbstractDatabase.java:126)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.algorithm.clustering.uncertain.FDBSCANNeighborPredicate.instantiate(FDBSCANNeighborPredicate.java:131)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.algorithm.clustering.gdbscan.GeneralizedDBSCAN.run(GeneralizedDBSCAN.java:122)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.algorithm.clustering.gdbscan.GeneralizedDBSCAN.run(GeneralizedDBSCAN.java:79)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.workflow.AlgorithmStep.runAlgorithms(AlgorithmStep.java:105)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.KDDTask.run(KDDTask.java:112)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.application.KDDCLIApplication.run(KDDCLIApplication.java:61)
    at [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

FDBSCAN requires data of the type `UncertainObject`, i.e. objects with uncertainty information.

If you simply load a CSV file, the data will be *certain*, and you cannot use uncertain clustering.

There are several ways of modeling uncertainty. These implement as *filters* in the `typeconversions` package.

- `UncertainSplitFilter` can split a vector of length k*N into k possible instances, each of length N with uniform weight.
- `WeightedUncertainSplitFilter` is similar, but every instance can also have a weight associated.
- `UncertainifyFilter` can simulate uncertainty by e.g. assuming a Gaussian or Uniform distribution around the original vector.

  - `UniformUncertainifier` (the U-Model, see Javadoc of `UniformContinuousUncertainObject`)
  - `SimpleGaussianUncertainifier` (see Javadoc of `SimpleGaussianContinuousUncertainObject`)
  - `UnweightedDiscreteUncertainifier` (BID Model, see Javadoc of `WeightedDiscreteUncertainObject`)
  - `WeightedDiscreteUncertainifier` (as above)
- or add your own uncertainty information by extending the API!

Comment: Thank you Erich! Could you please provide a sample of input file

Comment: Depends on what filter and uncertainty model you use. Usually regular CSV is fine; but you need to be clear on how the data should be interpreted as uncertain data.

Comment: basically I want to solve this problem http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250776/event-similarity-based-on-probability-distance-measure] , and I was really glad what I found that awesome tool. I dont know how to represent uncertaincy by distance distribution function, insted of points I have polygons (like cities) within which probability that event may occur is uniformly distributed

Comment: Well, there isn't a uncertainifier that would understand polygons yet. You could either write one (and use whatever input format you like), or you e.g. sample 100 points from each polygon, put them in one CSV line (of 200 values), and use the `UncertainSplitFilter` with the dimensionality set to 2.